# How to find which application changes a table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

Is it possible to find back which application made changes to a database (e.g. update a record)?
I'm using SQL Server 2012.

Comment: Why do you just add a flag. So when your inserting DB table you send a value from your application?

Comment: Are you trying to detect `who` is changing the table values currently or `who` did change the table values?

Comment: what "Recovery model" in SQL server enabled? if SIMPLE -- you cannot find out

Answer (score 0):

You might have to ask your `developers` to start including `Application Name` in their `connection string` in `web.config` files of their application.

```
Data Source=myServer;Initial Catalog=myDB;User Id=myUsername; Password=myPassword; Application Name=MyApplicationName;
```

Then you'll be able to use [APP_NAME](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189770.aspx) function to track the application connecting to the session or can also be used in the `store procs`.

Also, you can use `Application Name` to  filter queries in your `Sql Profiler`, otherwise in absence of Application Name, all application gets generic app name, `.NET sqlClient Data Provider`